# qmake: treat warning for missing .pri include as error

Tags: build, build-process, qmake

I have a qmake .pro file which includes a .pri file in a different directory.
When I run qmake and the .pri file is missing (say, because the work directory is not correctly set up), qmake gives the following output:

```
WARNING: c:\path\to\project.pro:20: Unable to find file for inclusion ..\..\path\to\include.pri
```

But qmake continues without error, i.e. the return value (ERRORLEVEL on windows) is 0. Thus, my automatic build continues and successfully builds, but with wrong settings, which is not caught by my build script.

How do I get qmake to treat "include file not found" as an error condition so I can check it from my build script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the include succeeded:

```
!include(../../path/to/include.pri): error(include file not found)
```

See also http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#include-filename

Comment: Indeed, I must have missed that part of the docs. I read "This function succeeds if filename is included; otherwise it fails" and wrongly assumed "fails" means it produces an error instead of continuing processing.
Thanks.